# Is the following same colour Bishop endgame position a win or a draw?

Tags: analysis, endgame, bishop-endgame

In a very recent European Team Championship, the following position appeared on the board. Is the following position a win for White or a draw? Help from FinalGen is welcome.

```
[fen "8/4k2p/1p6/p7/8/P1P5/2P1B1bP/1K6 w - - 0 0"]
```

Comment: How could you extract the FEN yet not have f.e. stockfish evaluate the position?

Comment: Or the questioni may be passed at TalkChess.com, where they have very powerful software And hardware.

Comment: @Stefano - you've asked a number of similar questions to this, *please* learn how to turn the FEN into a replayer, you will be much more likely to get responses. See https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179/how-do-i-add-a-replayer-to-my-post

Comment: Are you posting this as a chess problem/puzzle, or are you looking for the answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is might be a win for white if the puzzle above is white to move, as despite the stacked 2 pawns white has, black currently has 2 black squared pawns, which is the opposite color of the black bishop. So it is possible for the white king to chase down the two pawns after bb5 to prevent the black bishop from protecting the pawns or advancing the pawns. White can then move his king up.

Although I think it's possible for black to make a draw if the black king goes and protect these pawns, and then move the bishop continuously till draw without moving his king once the black king is on c5 to protect the b pawn

So considering that this is the European team championship and the people playing do not blunder, this is more probably a draw.

The above is written without the help of analysis, so I am probably wrong.

Edit: Analysis has shown at this position, with White to move,  is currently with an evaluation of 0.0--a draw basically. I ran the position on Stockfish 14+, so this is assuming that both players do not make any mistakes.

Comment: The black pawns stand perfectly on dark squares, where they cannot be targeted by the bishop. Even if White wasn't preventing it, Black should never play ...a4 nor ...b5. The second part of this answer is absolutely correct: this is a dead draw.